# AWK print specific line based on search pattern

Tags: unix, search, printing, awk, pattern-matching

I have two sets of files test.csv data.xml.

I am trying to grep a specific field from test.csv and search the string in data.xml. If string is found then print the corresponding line in test.csv file.

Example

search string is field 3 server name

**test.csv**

```
111,xxx,serversugar,port90
222,yyy,servertorque,port190
333,aaa,serverastrix,port8080
422,yxy,servertorque,port290
```

**data.xml**

```
<group>
<hostname>servertorque</hostname>
<hostname>serverastrix</hostname></group>
```

Output expected

```
222,yyy,servertorque,port190
333,aaa,serverastrix,port8080
422,yxy,servertorque,port290
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### with GNU sed & grep in 2 steps

```
sed '/>\w\+</!d;s/.*>\(\w\+\).*/\1/' data.xml>pattern.txt
grep -wf pattern.txt test.csv
```

..output:

```
222,yyy,servertorque,port190
333,aaa,serverastrix,port8080
422,yxy,servertorque,port290
```

Comment: @xtechkid `-w` option added to avoid to find server names like `servertorqueR`.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk`

```
awk -v FS="[><,]" 'NR==FNR{a[$3]++;next}$3 in a' data.xml test.csv
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat data.xml
<group>
<hostname>servertorque</hostname>
<hostname>serverastrix</hostname></group>

$ cat test.csv
111,xxx,serversugar,port90
222,yyy,servertorque,port190
333,aaa,serverastrix,port8080
422,yxy,servertorque,port290

$ awk -v FS="[><,]" 'NR==FNR {a[$3]++;next} $3 in a' data.xml test.csv
222,yyy,servertorque,port190
333,aaa,serverastrix,port8080
422,yxy,servertorque,port290
```

Comment: Thanks but am actually trying to do the reverse, the original xml is mix of multiple nodes i want to extract field $3 from test.csv and for each item in this file at this position($3) i want to search data.xml if the string exists in the file then remove the line from orginal file test.csv

Comment: Hmm, if the string exists and you wish to remove the line from original test.csv file then how is your desired output showing them?

Comment: am sorry it was supposed to be 'print the line'

Comment: What this does is it scans the xml file and if the node is present in test.csv it will print it. Isn't that the same?

Comment: i want to do the reverse (scan test.csv file) and search in the xml file, the reason is data.xml file in reality is a superset of test.csv my requirement is to pick strings from test.csv and search them in data.xml

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need:

```
awk -F',' '$3==<string_you_need> { print $0 }' test.csv
```

Comment: @Steven Thanks !! but the requirement is to get the search pattern as field value $3 from test.csv file.